# How to show hstore data relationship with other tables in a ERD?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some data that are designed weird! Now I want to create ERD for it.
But there are some problems.
There are some data stored in **hstore** which have relationship with the primary key of other tables.
To demonstrate, see the code below:

```
        CREATE EXTENSION hstore;
        CREATE TABLE books (
            id serial PRIMARY KEY,
            title VARCHAR (255),
            attr hstore
        );
        INSERT INTO books (title, attr)
        VALUES
            (
                'PostgreSQL Tutorial',
                '"paperback" => "243",
                 "publisher_id" => 1,
                 "language"  => "English",
                 "ISBN-13"   => "978-1449370000",
                 "weight"    => "11.2 ounces"'
            );
        INSERT INTO books (title, attr)
        VALUES
            (
                'PostgreSQL Cheat Sheet',
                '"paperback" => "5",
                 "publisher_id" => 2,
                 "language"  => "English",
                 "ISBN-13"   => "978-1449370001",
                 "weight"    => "1 ounces"'
            );
        CREATE TABLE publishers (
        publisher_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
        name varchar (50)
        );
        INSERT INTO publishers (name)
        VALUES ('publisher1'), ('publisher2');
```

There is no way to make **attr**->**publisher_id** a foreign key referencing to the **publisher_id** in the publishers table.
How I show their relationship in a diagram (preferably ERD)?
[image: Sample ERD]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your modelling tool doesn’t support hstore natively, then any diagram is going to be a logical, rather than physical, representation of your data.

In which case, why not just represent the hstore as a table? Assuming your ERD tool supports it, you could create a specific table type to represent hstores - so they are easily identifiable in your diagram

Comment: You mean something like [this ERD](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MrzYXE5H2N3bKl4DHXc4jqFZ-6TgPkks/view?usp=sharing)